# Spring Data REST updates null properties on PATCH (when it shouldn't)

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am sending a PATCH request with null values in some properties of the entity and I see that the fields are updated in the database whereas according to spec they shouldn't (partial update). Trying to understand what's going on I see that the DomainObjectMerger is instantiated as a @Bean but its merge method never used (no references found and in debug mode breakpoint is never fired). Could someone explain how and when is the DomainObjectMerger used?

EDIT: I created a sample project with a failing test. The test tries to PATCH an entity passing null as a password and expects the password to not have been affected. But it fails because the password is now null in the database

https://github.com/otinanism/demo-rest-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works as expected. Your PATCH payload looks like this:

```
{"id":"bc421109-edaf-4d4f-8d4c-71b62aa4d99f","username":"alex","password":null}
```

That's telling the server to wipe out the value for the `password` field. If you want to leave the password field untouched, make sure it's not even contained in the request payload, e.g. by configuring the `ObjectMapper` to not render `null` values.

Comment: This works indeed (but is it documented anywhere?). So, I suppose that DomainObjectMerger is unrelated to this? I got confused because of this old issuse:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-130
Thanksa lot for the feedback!

Comment: The behaviour is basically what's defined in [RFC7386](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7386).